# Grisanov theorem application

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations, local-martingales

I have the following Ito process: $X_t=e^{B_t-\frac{t}{2}}$ with $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion and I want to find under which probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ the process $X_t^3=e^{3B_t-\frac{3}{2}t}$ becomes a martingale.
The differential form of $X_t^3$ is applying Ito:
\begin{equation}
dX_t^3=3X_t^3dt+3X_t^3dB_t=3X_t^3(dt+dB_t)
\end{equation}
I'm looking for $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $dB_t^{\mathbb{Q}}=dB_t^\mathbb{P}+dt$. Thus applying Girsanov theorem such $\mathbb{Q}$ does exist if:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\bigg\lvert_t=\exp\bigg({-\int_0^tdB_s^{\mathbb{P}}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t ds\bigg)
\end{equation}
is a true martingale. This is easily verified since Novikov condition holds trivially because the process inside the expected value is purely deterministic.
\begin{equation}
E\bigg(\exp\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^tds\bigg)\bigg)<\infty
\end{equation}
Now I have that under $\mathbb{Q}$ the process $X_t^3$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion.

Now I'm asked to compute the following:
\begin{equation}
E^{\mathbb{Q}}(X_t)=\int Xd\mathbb{Q}=\int X\dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}d\mathbb{P}=E^\mathbb{P}(X\dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}})
\end{equation}
So replacing the Radon Nykodym derivative with $e^{-B^\mathbb{P}_t-\frac{t}{2}}$ I got:
\begin{equation}
E^{\mathbb{Q}}(X_t)=E^\mathbb{P}(X\dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}})=E^\mathbb{P}(e^{+B^\mathbb{P}_t-\frac{t}{2}}e^{-B^\mathbb{P}_t-\frac{t}{2}})=e^{-t}E(e^{B_t^\mathbb{P}-B_t^{\mathbb{P}}})=1
\end{equation}
where I used that $B_t^\mathbb{P}-B_t^\mathbb{P}\sim N(0,2t)$.

Now my problem is that I strongly think that the last assumption is not correct because the two Brownian motion are the same random variable and actually the difference is zero isn't it?

Comment: As you say, $B^{\mathbb P}_t-B^{\mathbb P}_t$ is zero. Therefore $E^{\mathbb Q}(X_t)$ should be $e^{-t}$.

Comment: A sanity check is also the following: You showed that $X^3_t$ is a $\mathbb Q$-martingale (not a $\mathbb Q$-BM BTW). Then by Jensen's inequality $X_t$ should be a $\mathbb Q$-supermartingale as $X_t$ is a concave function of $X^3_t$. This implies that $E^{\mathbb Q}(X_t)$ must be a decreasing function of $t$, and $e^{-t}$ is one.

Answer (score 1):

We answer the question at the beginning.

> I have the following Ito process: $X_t=e^{B_t-\frac{t}{2}}$ with $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion and I want to find under which probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ the process $X_t^3=e^{3B_t-\frac{3}{2}t}$ becomes a martingale.

We follow the [Gubinelli notes](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/gubinelli/stochastic-analysis-ss20/sa-ss20-script-9.pdf).

We observe that if $Z_{t}=e^{-\frac{6}{2}t}$, then

$$Y_{t}:=Z_{t}X_{t}^{3}=e^{3B_{t}-\frac{9}{2}t},$$

is a P-martingale due to $E_{P}[Y_{t}]=1$. Therefore, we let $\frac{dQ}{dP}|_{\mathcal{F}_{t}}=Z_{t}=e^{-6/2 t}$ and so by Bayes' formula

$$E_{Q}[X_{t}^{3}\mid \mathcal{F}_{s}]=\frac{1}{Z_{s}}E_{P}[Z_{t}X_{t}^{3}\mid \mathcal{F}_{s}]=X_{s}^{3}.$$